# Kotlin: Passing object from recyclerview to another fragment to edit when clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm just beginning to learn kotlin and my app is vey basic but this basic functionality has been giving me trouble the past couple of days.

I have one activity with two fragments (A and B) in my app. Fragment A is used to display the data in recyclerview. Fragment B is used to add data using edit texts/add button etc. That all works fine. Then when user selects an item in the recyclerview in Fragment A I want to navigate back to Fragment B passing an argument to say the user is now editing now adding and populate the edit texts with the selected items fields so the user can edit.

My Adapter:

```
class MoviesAdapter constructor(private var movies: List<MovieModel>)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MainHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainHolder {
    return MainHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.card_movie,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainHolder, position: Int) {
    val movie = movies[holder.adapterPosition]
    holder.bind(movie)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = movies.size

class MainHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(movie: MovieModel) {
        itemView.movie_view_Title.text = movie.title
        itemView.movie_view_director.text = movie.director
        itemView.movie_view_releaseDate.text = movie.releaseDate.toString()
        itemView.movie_view_ratingBar.rating = movie.rating.toFloat()
        itemView.movie_view_Image.setImageBitmap(readImageFromPath(itemView.context,movie.image))

        itemView.setOnClickListener{
        //Pass the movie item to Fragment B to edit & pass argument to say we are editing not adding
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: try with interface and pass you model class using parcable data

Answer (score 0):

1. add context in constructor

   ```
     class MoviesAdapter constructor (mCTX:Context,private var movies: List<MovieModel>){
   .....
   }
   ```
2. start Second `Activity` or `Fragment` using context in Adapter
3. Pass data using Android `Bundle()`

or
Implement a Interface